# Wygwam fields disappeared from entry screen

Tags: wygwam

I am using Wygwam 3.2.1 and it has been working fine, but now the field titles are showing on the entry screens but the field and text that had been previously entered is not visible. (it is still showing on the actual rendered website) It almost looks like it's minimised on the entry screen.

I have tried to overwrite the themes and system folders for Wygwam and run the module update, but still no go.

Could anyone help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem: I had added my own styles.js file but the link had an error in it. It was preventing Wygwam from loading.